# Query number of rows and columns in SQLite database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Currently, I have a database called "testDB.db" that has 100 rows and 3 columns. Is there some library in C# that allows me to easily check how many columns and rows there are in table "test001" in "testDB.db"?

```
namespace SQLiteExtractor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string liteString = @"Data Source = .\testDB.db";
            connectToSQLite(liteString);
        }

        public static void connectToSQLite(string liteConString)
        {
            using SQLiteConnection liteCon = new SQLiteConnection(liteConString);
            liteCon.Open();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM test001";
            int sizeOfDR = 0;
            List<string> liteEntries = new List<string>();

            using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, liteCon);
            using SQLiteDataReader SQLiteDR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (SQLiteDR.Read())
            {
                liteEntries.Add(SQLiteDR.GetString(1));
            }

            foreach (string entry in liteEntries)
                Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can get the number of rows by performing a select count(*) on the db side.

Comment: For rows you can do a `SELECT COUNT()`, for cols you can inspect the table metadata via system table queries I think? Looks like `PRAGMA table_info(table_name);` might work.

Comment: Yes a pragma table info will work, see this for info: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

Comment: I see that pragma works, but how would I go about storing the results from these SQL queries as C# variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rows, you can do a `SELECT COUNT()` query against the table.

For cols, you can inspect the table metadata via system table queries. Use `PRAGMA table_info(table_name);` to get the col info.

Specific to your table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test001
```

and

```
PRAGMA table_info('test001')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! Do you know how I would go about storing this information as variables in my C# Program?

Comment: @slam505 that should be a different question. Or perhaps search for a question along those lines which has already been answered!

Comment: got it, thank you. Do you happen to know how I could count the amount of columns on that PRAGMA statement? I tried SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRAGMA table_info('test001') however it just results in errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the number of columns, then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pragma_table_info('test001');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the count of rows from a table into a C# int64 variable (here called rowCount), if we say that conn already holds your SQLite database connection then....

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename", conn);
var rowCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```